# How to add button to Apple WatchKit Long Look notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, watchkit

Can someone please talk me through adding a button to a long-look local notification?  I'm new to both the watch kit and notifications.

The long-look is functioning correctly.  I'm setting up a `UILocalNotification` in my host app, setting the alertBody, category, userInfo, etc. and sending it off.

In my notification controller I'm setting everything up in `didReceiveLocalNotification` and it's working fine.

It seems, from my research, that I'm supposed to somehow add the button to the notification and use the method `handleActionWithIdentifier: forLocalNotification` but I'm unclear exactly how to do this.

I'm writing in Objective-C.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is notification payload I'm using:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": {
            "body": "Hi! How you doing? This is a test message. Press 'Reply' button to reply. Thanks!",
            "title": "Petya"
        },
        "category": "newMessage"
    },

    "WatchKit Simulator Actions": [
        {
            "title": "Reply",
            "identifier": "replyPressed"
        }
    ],
}
```

Create custom notification subclass and override following method and don't forget to set that subclass in corresponding storyboard controller:

```
override func didReceiveRemoteNotification(remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject], withCompletion completionHandler: (WKUserNotificationInterfaceType) -> Void) {
    if let aps = remoteNotification["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
      if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let title = alert["title"] as? String {
          titleLabel.setText(title)
        }
        if let body = alert["body"] as? String {
          bodyLabel.setText(body)
        }
      }
    }
    completionHandler(WKUserNotificationInterfaceType.Custom)
  }
```

After that in your notification custom button with title 'Reply' will appear. And when you press it it will launch watch app main interface controller and call `handleActionWithIdentifier:localNotification:` or `handleActionWithIdentifier:remoteNotification:`, depends on kind of notification you received. You have to override it like that:

```
override func handleActionWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification remoteNotification: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    println("identifier: \(identifier)")
    println("remoteNotification: \(remoteNotification)")
    if identifier == "replyPressed" {
      if let aps = remoteNotification["aps"] as? NSDictionary {
        if let alert = aps["alert"] as? NSDictionary {
          if let title = alert["title"] as? NSString {
            let context = Context()
            context.object = title
            pushControllerWithName(kTCChatRoomControllerIdentifier, context: context)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

P.S. `Context` is my own class for passing data between `WKInterfaceController`'s subclasses

Hope this will help you!)

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to figure out the swift.  When you say "notification payload" are you somehow loading the UILocalNotification with JSON then checking for the JSON in the `didReceiveLocalNotification` method?

Comment: You can create temporary notification payload file (basically JSON file) from Xcode->New File->Apple Watch->Notification Simulation File.

Comment: @MayNotBe asked about localNotifications not remoteNotifications, and localNotification don't work with Payload files

Answer (score 0):

The [Notification Essentials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQygQwAGoVChMIrJ7A0YyJxgIVyWitCh0QUwB0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FGeneral%2FConceptual%2FWatchKitProgrammingGuide%2FBasicSupport.html%23%2F%2Fapple_ref%2Fdoc%2Fuid%2FTP40014969-CH18-SW5&ei=kEJ6VayWGcnRtQWQpoGgBw&usg=AFQjCNHAfhRieCoRYEcOT9K3i4sl8IeoTw&sig2=uDOckHSdd442d1P6f6udAQ&bvm=bv.95515949,d.b2w) section of the Apple Watch Programming Guide describes how to add action buttons to Long-Look notifications for local notifications.

Basically, you need to create a UIMutableUserNotificationAction for every button that you want to add to your Long-Look interface, along with a category for your local notification. This is done in the App Delegate of your **iOS app**, when you register for notifications. Listing 15-1 in that guide shows exactly how to do it. Then, in the storyboard for your Apple Watch app, set your notification's category to the category you just created. The next section of the guide, "Responding to Taps in Action Buttons," should hopefully tell you everything you need to know in order to either launch your WatchKit app, or execute a task in the background on the iPhone.